# Issue with regex expression used to extract timestamps from XML file

Tags: c++, regex, xml

I am aiming to implement regex into my C++ program in an attempt to extract timestamps, among other things from an XML file. Right now I am focusing on creating a regex expression to extract 6 timestamps in particular from the XML file. Unfortunately, I my regex expression does not seem to be locating the 6 timestamps I want it to. The expression I have created is: `\2\0\1\4\\-\0\7\-\0\8\T\1\8\:\1\4\:\.\.\\.\7\1\6\Z`. If you look at the XML file which I have linked below, I am trying to extract the timestamps from 6 lines in particular(lines 72,75,78,81,84,and 87). Could someone possibly help me point out what is being done wrong? Sorry, I'm just getting familiarizing myself with Regex for the first time. I am using http://regexr.com/ to test my expressions.

Link to XML file: http://pastebin.com/5hMy9RzK

Six timestamps which I want my regex expression to locate:

timestamp="2014-07-08T18:14:17.716Z"

timestamp="2014-07-08T18:14:18.716Z

timestamp="2014-07-08T18:14:19.716Z

timestamp="2014-07-08T18:14:20.716Z

timestamp="2014-07-08T18:14:21.716Z

timestamp="2014-07-08T18:14:22.716Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression looks strange, you are escaping every *literal* character with a `\` which is usually only used for special characters.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\w\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.716Z
```

Example:
http://regexr.com/3cbs2

Comment: I want to only extract those 6 specific timestamps however, and what you have extracts every timestamp, which are made unique by the "716z" at the end. I need my regex expression to accommodate that.

Comment: @Mrcitrusboots That's easily accommodated. Is the new answer fixed?

Comment: Thank you that's perfect! Sorry, I'm just getting introduced to Regex.